# Организация базы данных

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Возникла необходимость организовать базу данных с неопределенным количеством элементов. т.е. имеется база о человеке. Поля стандартные - фото, фио, ...
Но возникла необходимость добавить увлечения для каждого человека. Количество увлечений ограничено допустим в 255. Человек сам может добавить увлечение (на подобии облака тегов). Как это проще реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 6):

Делается ещё одна таблица, в которой три поля: id, id человека, названия увлечения. А ещё можно сделать отдельно таблицу со списком всех увлечений, а в первую записывать не название, а просто номер.

Плюсы:

- можно легко найти людей с одинаковыми увлечениями
- можно легко найти людей, которые не имеют увлечений.

Comment: Спасибо. Видимо к вечеру соображалка почти не работает :)

Answer (score -1):

На пример в базе хранить поле "увлечения" в котором сохранять XML или JSON...